# Managing duplicates in a binary tree with memory efficiency

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a self balancing key-value binary tree (similar to Tarjan's Zip Tree) where there will be duplication of keys. To ensure O(log N) performance the only thing I can come up with is to maintain three pointers per node; a less than, a greater than, and an "equals". The equals pointer is a pointer to a linked-list of members having the same key.

This seems memory inefficient to me because I'll have an extra 8 bytes per node in the whole tree to handle the infrequent duplicate occurrences.  Is there a better way that doesn't involve "cheats" like bit banging the left or right pointers for use as a flag?

Comment: How many nodes are we talking about?

Comment: Of course you could say something like if(data == node->value) return;

Comment: @jwdonahue . I test with 50,000,000.

Comment: Is value data locality to node address a requirement?

Comment: @jwdonahue: Yes locality is important to me. I don't want to do an extra pointer dereference because that's less cache friendly.

Comment: Is a node reallocation on insertion collision acceptable? What about value data alignment? Is it a byte array?

Comment: Why not make sure that nodes with identical keys are descendants of each other during insertion, and always on the same side? Then your look-ups could have a simple "are there any more of these" check.

Comment: @jwdonahue the data struct is variable size and potentially large. realloc is an option, but it might entail a giant memmove.  The struct uses a flexible array member to store key and value data. It's contents are anonymous to me because the user supplies the node and the compare. ie: { NODE *leftOrRight[2]; byte payload[]; }

Comment: @m69 because that potentially violates O(log N) in that replicate keys become a linked list.

Comment: You'd have to assess the likelihood of duplicates; depending on what you mean by "infrequent", it may not make much of a difference.

Comment: @m69 That's true. I'm just trying to avoid a potentially bad trap. I test with 50 million nodes and expect more in production. log2(50e6) is 26 compares. If the user inserted a mere 100 duplicates that would increase it to 126 for all children nodes of the duplicates.

Comment: Use a one or two byte hash of the pointer to the duplicates list. Set it zero when there's no dupes.

Comment: @jwdonahue, do you mean { NODE *lr[2]; uint16_t hash; byte payload[];} ?  I'm not sure I understand your solution, but it sounds promising.

Comment: Is this a system that is already in production? Have you profiled it?

Comment: My answer has been updated.

Comment: It's not in production yet. when testing with 100,000,000 nodes I'm getting about 5.5 million operations / sec. An operation being insert, delete, update, or search.

Comment: Wow, that must be a very robust machine. What's the min/max/avg size of the data in your nodes?

Comment: @jwdonahue The tests are just uint64s generated with an xorShift RNG. That way I can easily validate all the ops. (btw that was on a 2016 Macbook pro.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181410/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-eddingtonsmonkey).

Answer (score 2):

- When you have a collision insertion, allocate new buffer, copy new data.
- Hash the new data pointer down to one or two bytes. You'll need a hash that only returns zero on zero input!
- Store the hash value in your node. This field would be zero if there are no collision data, so you are O(log KeyCount) for all keys without extra data elements. You're worst case is log KeyCount plus whatever your hashing algorithm yields on lookups, which might be a constant close to 1 additional step until your table has to be resized.

Obviously, choice of hashing algorithm is critical here. Look for one that is good with pointer values on whatever architecture you are targeting. You may need different hashes for different architectures.

You can carry this even further by using only one byte hash values that get you the hash table that you then use the key hash (can be a larger integer) to find the pointer to the additional data. When a hash table fills up, insert a new one into the parent table. I'll leave the math to you.

Regarding data locality. Since the node data are large, you already don't have good node record to actual data locality anyway. This scheme doesn't change that, except in the case where you have multiple data nodes for a particular key, in which case, you'd likely have cache miss getting to the correct index of a variable array embedded in the node. This scheme avoids having to reallocate the nodes on collisions, and probably won't have a severe impact on your cache miss rate.

Comment: This has the advantage that if no dupes are ever encountered, the performance is never degenerate. You get good data locality everywhere, except when you have to use the hash to lookup another table or additional data and then the penalty can be kept quite small with careful selection of hashing algorithms. Your space requirements are kept quite low as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm ingesting your answer be back soon.

Comment: If you look at your pointers, you'll see that some number most significant bits are fixed for a given heap. Since you also have large data blocks, there's a bunch of bits on the LSB side that can't contribute anything to the hash value either. Trim those, then hash the rest down to a smaller data size and you've solved your problem. In other words, you can reduce the hash function input size by one or more bytes with a mask, shift and truncation. Then you can further reduce the size of the reference stored in your nodes by hashing it down to a smaller size.

Comment: Pointers are NOT integers, they don't have random distributions. Precondition your pointers prior to hashing them, that will help a great deal.

Comment: All good ideas. Thanks! I considered bit bashing the left or right node pointer to add a flag like some red-black tree implementations do, but the disadvantage was that it requires everyone to know that the pointer is invalid until the flag bit is cleared.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use this setup when i do a binary search tree, it skips in an array the duplicates values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 13

typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node * right;
  struct Node * left;
  int value;
}TNode;

typedef  TNode * Nodo;

void bst(int data, Nodo * p )
{
Nodo pp = *p;
  if(pp == NULL)
  {
    pp = (Nodo)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    pp->right = NULL;
    pp->left = NULL;
    pp->value = data;
    *p = pp;
  }
  else if(data == pp->value)
    {
      return;
    }
  else  if(data > pp->value)
    {
      bst(data, &pp->right);
    }
  else
    {
      bst(data, &pp->left);
    }

  }

void displayDesc(Nodo p)
{
  if(p != NULL)
  {

  displayDesc(p->right);
  printf("%d\n", p->value);
  displayDesc(p->left);

  }
}

void displayAsc(Nodo p)
{
  if(p != NULL)
  {

  displayAsc(p->left);
  printf("%d\n", p->value);
  displayAsc(p->right);

  }
}


int main()
{
  int arr[SIZE] = {4,1,0,7,5,88,8,9,55,42,0,5,6};

Nodo head = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    bst(arr[i], &head);
  }

displayAsc(head);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP implied a one to many relation between keys and data.

Comment: As I said above, I'm storing keys & values in the tree, the keys might be duplicates, but the values are the payload. The values may also be duplicate. Your code just returns on duplicate.